# ASP Core razor pages generating data different from the view model

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm completely stumped as to why a Razor page in ASP Core would be generating content when the view model clearly has no such content.  To test this, from within the same app, I've created a test view model, controller and razor page to demonstrate the problem.

The goal of this proof/test is simple: Provide a simple form, explicitly **clear the contents** in the receiving controller, and **return an empty form** to the user.

The problem is that the razor page is still **generating the previously submitted content** even when the three model fields are **explicitly cleared** (as confirmed by inspection in debugging, as seen in screenshots further below).

I even have `services.AddResponseCaching();` commented-out in the `Startup.cs` file.

Here's the code:

## Controller

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult TestForm(int id)
{
    ViewModels.TestFormViewModel viewModel = new ViewModels.TestFormViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult TestForm(int id, ViewModels.TestFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    // The following should clear out the three text fields:
    viewModel.TestField1 = ""; // See if empty string works.
    viewModel.TestField2 = null; // See if null works.
    viewModel.TestField3 = null;            
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

## View Model

```cs
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class TestFormViewModel
    {
        [Section("1")]
        public string TestField1 { get; set; }

        [Section("1")]
        public string TestField2 { get; set; }

        [Section("1")]
        public string TestField3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Razor Page (.cshtml)

```html
@model MyApp.ViewModels.TestFormViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test Page";
}
<p>The input on this page should be cleared every time it's submitted:</p>
<form name="myapp-form" id="myapp-form" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div>
        <input asp-for="TestField1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="TestField2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="TestField3" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

As you can see in the following debug shot, the code inspector shows that 1) the code is routing the POST request properly, and 2) the three string properties of the view model have been cleared of submitted input (one with null, the others with empty string):

[image: inspecting the view model in the controller]

Then, inspecting the `this.Model` of the razor page, I confirm the three string properties are exactly as the controller handed to the razor page:

[image: inspecting this.Model of the razor page]

Yet the razor page is generating `<input>` tags with the exact content that was submitted (but cleared-out!) by the controller:

[image: form output by the razor page after submit]

Here's the form HTML (as captured directly from the body of the HTTP response, *not* by "view source") confirming that the "value" attributes of the `<input>` tags contain data different from the above view model handed to the razor page.

```html
<form name="myapp-form" id="myapp-form" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="TestField1" name="TestField1" value="This test" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="TestField2" name="TestField2" value="should be" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="TestField3" name="TestField3" value="cleared out" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="[token redacted]" />
</form>
```

All the above (seems) to prove that browser cannot be inserting or otherwise populating this data.

Why is the razor page generating content not in the model??

I've tried everything I can think of and I'm still unable to determine why this is happening.  Can the ASP Core experts help me out?

Comment: It's because the values are read from `ModelState` when they exist in there. You can at least prove that by adding `ModelState.Clear()`.

Comment: Thanks @KirkLarkin  I have a need to clear/empty selected values after a user submits a form, _and_ I need to do it from within the ViewModel (based on custom validation, of course). If the Razor page is pulling content from the ModelState instead of the VIewModel, what am I do to?

Comment: If you don't want the fields to repopulate from ModelState, don't use tag helpers. They automatically bind the values to the inputs. Use plain HTML inputs, setting the name explicitly.